# SQL Server: Dynamic where-clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance

**Problem:**

Ajax suggest-search on [*n*] ingredients in recipes. That is: match recipes against multiple ingredients.

For instance: `SELECT Recipes using "flower", "salt"` would produce: `"Pizza", "Bread", "Saltwater"` and so forth.

**Tables:**

```
Ingredients [
    IngredientsID INT [PK],
    IngredientsName VARCHAR
]

Recipes [
    RecipesID INT [PK],
    RecipesName VARCHAR
]

IngredientsRecipes [
    IngredientsRecipesID INT [PK],
    IngredientsID INT,
    RecipesID INT
]
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    Recipes.RecipesID,
    Recipes.RecipesName,
    Ingredients.IngredientsID,
    Ingredients.IngredientsName
FROM
    IngredientsRecipes

    INNER JOIN Ingredients
    ON IngredientsRecipes.IngredientsID = Ingredients.IngredientsID

    INNER JOIN Recipes
    ON IngredientsRecipes.RecipesID = Recipes.RecipesID
WHERE
    Ingredients.IngredientsName IN ('salt', 'water', 'flower')
```

I am currently constructing my query using ASP.NET C# because of the dynamic nature of the `WHERE` clause.

I bites that I have to construct the query in my code-layer instead of using a stored procedure/pure SQL, which in theory should be much faster.

Have you guys got any thoughts on how I would move all of the logic from my code-layer to pure SQL, or at least how I can optimize the performance of what I'm doing?

I am thinking along the lines of temporary tables:

**Step one**: `SELECT IngredientsID FROM Ingredients` and `INSERT INTO temp-table`

**Step two**: `SELECT RecipesName FROM Recipes` joined with `IngredientsRecipes` joined with `temp-table.IngredientsID`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options. If you're using SQL Server 2008 (or Oracle) you can pass in a [table value parameter](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters).

If you're using SQL Server 2005, you can use [XML to simulate this capability](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx)

If you're using something earlier than 2005, you need to concatenate the ids in a single string and create a UDF to parse them.

Answer (score 3):

You could at least parametrize the where clausule to avoid SQL injection, something alike:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

class Foo
{
    public static void Main ()
    {
        string[] parameters = {"salt", "water", "flower"};
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection ();
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand ();
        StringBuilder where = new StringBuilder ();
        for (int i = 0; i < parametes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
                where.Append (",");
            where.AppendFormat ("@Param{0}", i);
            command.Parameters.Add (new SqlParameter ("Param" + i, parameters [i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I was taking care of potential injections. Mike Brown came up with a stroke of genius. But thanks for your effort mate.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you are processing the input ingredients I think this current method has some sql injection risks.

You could append the ingrediant name to the join conditions which may be quicker.

You could also hash combinations of ingredients for receipes for a quick lookup.

Comment: I agree. Script injection issues is also one of my concerns. Could you elaborate on "hasing"?

Comment: If you have the user choose from a list of possible ingredients, the one's in your ingredients table, you could programmaticly use those ids, in your where statement and no injection issue.

Comment: E.g. If you process an MD5 or SHA1 hash by appending the words salt water flour you will get one value (your hash). In your lookup you could then just look for this an item matching this. 
As you are comparing one value rather than a list it would be quicker.

Comment: That would only give him an exact match. the logic of the sample query implies he wants recipes that contain any of the ingredients.

Now that you mention it though one trick would be to use a bitmask for your values.