# whats the difference between a stored procedure and a table valued function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

whats the difference between a stored procedure and a table valued function?
they seem to serve the same functions

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178128/functions-vs-stored-procedures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table-valued functions can return only a single result set; SPs can return multiple result sets.

You can subsequently query over the results of table-valued functions - but not with SPs.

So table-valued functions are more flexible if you don't need multiple result sets.

Comment: "SPs can return multiple result sets" -- or, indeed, none i.e. they may just 'do stuff' and return a return value and/or raise warnings and/or errors.