# sql server: passing the parameter to the view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how can I pass the parameter to view in sql server.I have a stok which contain stok info including the quantity.I have a form and via this form I added the quatitiy to the  stok .
what I need is get the form value of quatitiy and add the the stok quantity which is available values.for this that I need the pass parameter to the view which automatically add this value to  current value in the stok,
thank you all for help

Comment: Sorry, you cannot. See here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687279/can-we-pass-parameter-to-a-view-in-sql

Comment: Better then you will be use store procedure and pass parameter. It's also working like view select query.

Comment: Try to use `CONTEXT_INFO`

Comment: hmm possiable but what if I wanna use view

Comment: devart can u clerify little bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use a table function such as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TblFunc_AAA]
(
@ID BIGINT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
SELECT *
FROM MyTable 
where aaa = @ID
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually views are only stored as SELECTs on a database, so you can't pass a parameter to it.

A stored procedure / function will fit right in. Declare one taking a parameter and only do a `SELECT ... WHERE val = @paramval`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc
@in_quantity int
AS
SELECT * FROM tbl1
WHERE val = @in_quantity
GO;
```