# Loading certain number of rows from DataReader into datatable

Tags: c#, t-sql, datagridview

I have a process which loads a DataGridView from a TSql view. There has been a debate amongst my users on whether to return all the rows or a certain number (im in the latter camp: TOP 100). I decided that the best approach would be to return the number of rows dynamically based on a field set by the user. I was expecting this to be a fairly trivial task. I was expecting to load a datatable with a while loop and a read function and stop at a certain number of rows. Is this possible? Is there a huge benefit in keeping the code as it is below, but cutting the datatable (dt) down to the desired number of rows and then loading the datagridview from there?

```
         public void Load_DGV(DataGridView dgv, string sqlx)
    {
        DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlx.ToString());

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default._CONNSTRING);
        command.Connection = connection;

        bool Success = true;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
       dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

        connection.Close();

        dgv.DataSource = null;
        dgv.DataSource = dt;
        Color_DGV(dgvProposal);

        dgvProposal.Sort(dgvProposal.Columns[m_Current_Menu_Item.OrderByCol], ListSortDirection.Descending);
        DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Execution of " + sqlx + " took " + (d2 - d1).Seconds.ToString() + "s. ");
    }
```

Comment: Thats probably the best way around this situation. Unfortunately my Query is absolutely massive and needs to be updated frequently, so i placed it in a view which cannot have parameters. The other alternative is a stored procedure, which is my fall back worst case scenario. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: a view supports top x

Comment: yes. but it doesnt support parameters. The rows i return must be dynamic at runtime

Comment: A view doesn't support parameters? How about a Where clause? ADO.NET supports parameterized SQL Strings natively without having to create a sproc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Comment: yes, but i dont want to hardcode an 82 line sql query in my code as i need to change it. Everything ive read so far is that views dont easily and natively support parameters. What you are suggesting is what i think i will do for a stored procedure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687279/can-we-pass-parameter-to-a-view-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

You'll get way better performance if you change things up so you can pass a parameter indicating the number of `TOP` rows to return.

Otherwise, once you load all the records into a new `DataTable`, you can use LINQ to `TAKE` the first xx rows, and assign that to the `DataSource`.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Take(100).CopyToDataTable();
```

You might save some processing time if you used `reader.Read()` to iterate through the first 100 records, and manually filled a `DataTable`. At least then you're not filling a `DataTable` with thousands of records just to discard it and create *another*, smaller `DataTable`.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking, but then you have overhead of converting the read() record to a datarow. I think your TOP suggestion is the best bet. Ill have to refactor some code.