# How to create view from the given set of code

Tags: sql-server

I have never come across such a large amount of code and I want to make a View with exact same output that my SQL query is generating. The code is exceeding the limit hence I have reduced the code though the code is incomplete but I have tried making view by create view view name but I am unable to make.

I have tried `create view view_name as (sql query)` but its showing error:

> incorrect syntax 'declare'

But when run alone this whole SQL query we are getting result. Is declare part is the problem?

```
      DECLARE @ClientCode VARCHAR(20);
        SELECT @ClientCode = FlagValue
        FROM ApplicationConfiguration
        WHERE FlagName = 'ClientCode';
        DECLARE @NoOfColorsInDashboardGraphs VARCHAR(10);
        SELECT @NoOfColorsInDashboardGraphs = FlagValue
        FROM ApplicationConfiguration
        WHERE FlagName = 'NoOfColorsInDashboardGraphs';
        DECLARE @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasks VARCHAR(50);
        SELECT @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasks = FlagValue
        FROM ApplicationConfiguration
        WHERE FlagName = 'TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasks';
        DECLARE @TerminologyToNonCompliedNonCompletedTasks VARCHAR(50);
        SELECT @TerminologyToNonCompliedNonCompletedTasks = FlagValue
        FROM ApplicationConfiguration
        WHERE FlagName = 'TerminologyToNonCompliedNonCompletedTasks';
        DECLARE @DeviationFunctionality VARCHAR(50);
        SELECT @DeviationFunctionality = FlagValue
        FROM ApplicationConfiguration
        WHERE FlagName = 'DeviationFunctionality';
        DECLARE @ShowPerformedOnDate VARCHAR(10);
        SELECT @ShowPerformedOnDate = FlagValue
        FROM ApplicationConfiguration
        WHERE FlagName = 'ShowPerformedOnDate';
        DECLARE @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasksPerformedOnDtAfterDueDt VARCHAR(50);
        SELECT @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasksPerformedOnDtAfterDueDt = FlagValue
        FROM ApplicationConfiguration
        WHERE FlagName = 'TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasksPerformedOnDtAfterDueDt';
        DECLARE @TerminologyToCompliedTasks VARCHAR(50);
        SELECT @TerminologyToCompliedTasks = FlagValue
        FROM ApplicationConfiguration
        WHERE FlagName = 'TerminologyToCompliedTasks';
        DECLARE @TerminologyToPosingRiskTasks VARCHAR(50);
        SELECT @TerminologyToPosingRiskTasks = FlagValue
        FROM ApplicationConfiguration
        WHERE FlagName = 'TerminologyToPosingRiskTasks';
        SELECT TL.OID, 
               E.EntityOID, 
               U.UnitOID, 
               D.DeptOID, 
               E.EntityName, 
               U.UnitName, 
               D.DeptName, 
               (CASE
                    WHEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(U.ShortDesc)), '') = ''
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), UT.UnitTaskOID)
                    ELSE U.ShortDesc + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), UT.UnitTaskOID)
                END) AS 'UnitTaskWithDesc', 
               UT.[UnitTaskOID], 
               UT.[TaskOID], 
               T.LegislationOID, 
               T.CentralTaskOID, 
               L.LegislationCategoryOID, 
               C.LegislationCategory, 
               ISNULL(
        (
            SELECT C.CompanyCategory
            FROM CompanyCategory C
            WHERE C.CompanyCategoryOID = T.CompanyCategoryOID
        ), '-') CompanyCategory, 
               L.CentralState, 
               L.LegislationName, 
               T.Section_Rule_Regulation_Notification, 
               S.STATE_OID, 
               S.STATE_NAME, 
               T.[Title], 
               T.[PriorityOID], 
               P.Priority, 
               T.[FrequencyOID], 
               F.Frequency, 
               T.[Devices], 
               T.[Section_Rule_Regulation_Notification], 
               T.[Requirement_Apply], 
               T.[Task], 
               T.[Regulating_Authority], 
               T.[Consequences], 
               T.[Department], 
               TL.[Status] AS TaskStatus, 
               UT.PerformerUserOID, 
               D.DeptHeadOID, 
               ISNULL((UDFH.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UDFH.LAST_NAME), '-') AS 'DeptHead', 
               UT.DeptSupervisorOID, 
               ISNULL((UDSup.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UDSup.LAST_NAME), '-') AS 'Supervisor', 
               TL.PerformerUserOID AS 'PerformerUserOID_log', 
               ISNULL((UDPer.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UDPer.LAST_NAME), '-') AS 'Performer', 
               ISNULL((UDComp.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UDComp.LAST_NAME), '-') AS 'TaskCompletedBy', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.ApproverDt) AS 'ApproverDt', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.ReviewerDt) AS 'ReviewerDt', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.SupervisorDt) AS 'SupervisorDt', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.PerformerDt) AS 'PerformerDt',
               CASE
                   WHEN @DeviationFunctionality = 'Yes'
                   THEN ISNULL(TL.Deviation, '-')
                   ELSE ''
               END AS 'Deviation', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.PerformedOnDt) AS 'PerformedOnDt', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.CompletedDt) AS 'CompletedDt', 
               ISNULL(TL.Comments, '-') AS 'Comments', 
               ISNULL(TL.ActivationComment, '-') AS ActivationComment, 
               ISNULL(TL.ReasonForNonComp, '-') AS 'ReasonForNonComp', 
               ISNULL(TL.ActionTaken, '-') AS 'ActionTaken', 
               dbo.GetCompletionDate(@ClientCode, TL.CompletedDt, @ShowPerformedOnDate, @NoOfColorsInDashboardGraphs, TL.PerformedOnDt) AS 'Completed On', 
               dbo.GetCompletionComment(TL.ActivationComment, TL.Comments, TL.ReviewerComment, TL.CompletedDt, TL.ReviewerCommentDate, TL.PeriodFromDate, TL.PeriodToDate) AS 'CompletionComments', 
               '' AS UnitDeviceOID, 
               '' AS TaskDeviceOID, 
               '' AS 'lblUnitDeviceOIDDesc', 
               dbo.GetComplianceStatus(TL.[Status], CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), TL.ApproverDt, 112)), CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), TL.CompletedDt, 112)), @NoOfColorsInDashboardGraphs, @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasks, @TerminologyToNonCompliedNonCompletedTasks, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), TL.PerformedOnDt, 112)), @ShowPerformedOnDate, @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasksPerformedOnDtAfterDueDt, @TerminologyToCompliedTasks, @TerminologyToPosingRiskTasks) AS 'ComplianceStatus', 
               ISNULL(TblLOGTMakerChecker.ConditionalOID, 0) AS MKOID, 
               ISNULL(TCSV.TaskComplianceStatusValue, '-') AS TaskComplianceStatusValue, 
               ISNULL(TL.TaskComplianceStatusValueOID, 0) AS TaskComplianceStatusValueOID, 
               @NoOfColorsInDashboardGraphs AS 'NoOfColorsOnReport', 
               @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasks AS 'TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTask', 
               @TerminologyToNonCompliedNonCompletedTasks AS 'TerminologyToNonCompliedNonCompletedTask', 
               @ShowPerformedOnDate AS 'ShowPerformedOnDate', 
               @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasksPerformedOnDtAfterDueDt AS 'TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasksPerformedOnDtAfterDueDt', 
               @TerminologyToCompliedTasks AS 'TerminologyToCompliedTasks', 
               (CASE
                    WHEN(
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM UnitTaskDocs
            WHERE UnitTaskOID = UT.UnitTaskOID
                  AND DueDateId = TL.OID
        ) > 0)
                    THEN 'Yes'
                    ELSE 'No'
                END) AS 'DocumentUploaded', 
               dbo.FormatDate
        (@ClientCode,
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 UPLOADED_DATE
            FROM UnitTaskDocs
            WHERE UnitTaskOID = UT.UnitTaskOID
                  AND DueDateId = TL.OID
            ORDER BY 1 DESC
        )
        ) AS 'DocUploadedDate', 
               'No' AS 'DocumentUploadLater', 
               TL.FeesPaid, 
               TL.PenaltyPaid, 
               TL.SecondSupervisorComment, 
               TL.SecondSupervisorCommentDate, 
               TL.ThirdSupervisorComment, 
               TL.ThirdSupervisorCommentDate, 
               '' AS TaskType, 
               '-' AS Region, 
               '-' AS SubRegion
        FROM UnitTask UT
             INNER JOIN Task T ON T.Task_OID = UT.TaskOID
             INNER JOIN LegislationNames L ON L.LegislationOID = T.LegislationOID
             INNER JOIN LegislationCategories C ON C.LegislationCategoryOID = L.LegislationCategoryOID
             INNER JOIN [STATE] S ON S.STATE_OID = L.StateOID
             INNER JOIN Dept D ON D.DeptOID = UT.PerformerDeptOID
             INNER JOIN Units U ON U.UnitOID = UT.UnitOID
             INNER JOIN Entity E ON E.EntityOID = U.EntityOID
             INNER JOIN Priority P ON P.PriorityOID = T.PriorityOID
             INNER JOIN Frequency F ON F.FrequencyOID = T.FrequencyOID
             INNER JOIN ConditionalTaskLog TL ON TL.UnitTaskOID = UT.UnitTaskOID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN ConditionalMakerChecker TblLOGTMakerChecker ON TL.OID = TblLOGTMakerChecker.ConditionalOID
                                                                            AND TblLOGTMakerChecker.STATUS = 0
             LEFT OUTER JOIN TaskComplianceStatusValue TCSV ON TL.TaskComplianceStatusValueOID = TCSV.OID
             INNER JOIN LTGN_USER_DETAIL UDFH ON UDFH.USER_OID = D.DeptHeadOID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN LTGN_USER_DETAIL UDSup ON UDSup.USER_OID = TL.DeptSupervisorOID
             INNER JOIN LTGN_USER_DETAIL UDPer ON UDPer.USER_OID = TL.PerformerUserOID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN LTGN_USER_DETAIL UDComp ON UDComp.USER_OID = TL.CompletedByUserOID
        WHERE UT.[Status] = 'Active'
              AND UT.TaskStatus = 'Assigned'
              AND T.Devices = 'No'
              AND T.Title <> 'Applicability'
              AND L.LegislationCategoryOID NOT IN(117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125)
             AND T.CentralTaskOID NOT IN
        (
            SELECT CentralTaskOID
            FROM GroupTask
        )
             AND U.EntityOID IN(27, 25, 26, 24)
        AND u.UnitOID = UT.UnitOID
        AND ((TL.ReviewerDt >= '12/17/2019'
              AND TL.ReviewerDt <= '03/17/2020'
              AND TL.PerformerDt <= '03/17/2020')
             OR (TL.CompletedDt BETWEEN '12/17/2019' AND '03/17/2020')
             OR (TL.ApproverDt >= '12/17/2019'
                 AND TL.ApproverDt <= '03/17/2020'))
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TL.OID, 
               E.EntityOID, 
               U.UnitOID, 
               D.DeptOID, 
               E.EntityName, 
               U.UnitName, 
               D.DeptName, 
               (CASE
                    WHEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(U.ShortDesc)), '') = ''
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), UT.UnitTaskOID)
                    ELSE U.ShortDesc + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), UT.UnitTaskOID)
                END) AS 'UnitTaskWithDesc', 
               UT.[UnitTaskOID], 
               UT.[TaskOID], 
               T.LegislationOID, 
               T.CentralTaskOID, 
               L.LegislationCategoryOID, 
               C.LegislationCategory, 
               ISNULL(
        (
            SELECT C.CompanyCategory
            FROM CompanyCategory C
            WHERE C.CompanyCategoryOID = T.CompanyCategoryOID
        ), '-') CompanyCategory, 
               L.CentralState, 
               L.LegislationName, 
               T.Section_Rule_Regulation_Notification, 
               S.STATE_OID, 
               S.STATE_NAME, 
               T.[Title], 
               T.[PriorityOID], 
               P.Priority, 
               T.[FrequencyOID], 
               F.Frequency, 
               T.[Devices], 
               T.[Section_Rule_Regulation_Notification], 
               T.[Requirement_Apply], 
               T.[Task], 
               T.[Regulating_Authority], 
               T.[Consequences], 
               T.[Department], 
               TL.[Status] AS TaskStatus, 
               UT.PerformerUserOID, 
               D.DeptHeadOID, 
               ISNULL((UDFH.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UDFH.LAST_NAME), '-') AS 'DeptHead', 
               UT.DeptSupervisorOID, 
               ISNULL((UDSup.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UDSup.LAST_NAME), '-') AS 'Supervisor', 
               TL.PerformerUserOID AS 'PerformerUserOID_log', 
               ISNULL((UDPer.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UDPer.LAST_NAME), '-') AS 'Performer', 
               ISNULL((UDComp.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UDComp.LAST_NAME), '-') AS 'TaskCompletedBy', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.ApproverDt) AS 'ApproverDt', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.ReviewerDt) AS 'ReviewerDt', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.SupervisorDt) AS 'SupervisorDt', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.PerformerDt) AS 'PerformerDt',
               CASE
                   WHEN @DeviationFunctionality = 'Yes'
                   THEN ISNULL(TL.Deviation, '-')
                   ELSE ''
               END AS 'Deviation', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.PerformedOnDt) AS 'PerformedOnDt', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.CompletedDt) AS 'CompletedDt', 
               ISNULL(TL.Comments, '-') AS 'Comments', 
               ('-') AS 'ActivationComment', 
               ISNULL(TL.ReasonForNonComp, '-') AS 'ReasonForNonComp', 
               ISNULL(TL.ActionTaken, '-') AS 'ActionTaken', 
               dbo.GetCompletionDate(@ClientCode, TL.CompletedDt, @ShowPerformedOnDate, @NoOfColorsInDashboardGraphs, TL.PerformedOnDt) AS 'Completed On', 
               dbo.GetCompletionComment('', TL.Comments, TL.ReviewerComment, TL.CompletedDt, TL.ReviewerCommentDate, TL.PeriodFromDate, TL.PeriodToDate) AS 'CompletionComments', 
               '' AS UnitDeviceOID, 
               '' AS TaskDeviceOID, 
               '' AS 'lblUnitDeviceOIDDesc', 
               dbo.GetComplianceStatus(TL.[Status], CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), TL.ApproverDt, 112)), CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), TL.CompletedDt, 112)), @NoOfColorsInDashboardGraphs, @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasks, @TerminologyToNonCompliedNonCompletedTasks, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), TL.PerformedOnDt, 112)), @ShowPerformedOnDate, @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasksPerformedOnDtAfterDueDt, @TerminologyToCompliedTasks, @TerminologyToPosingRiskTasks) AS 'ComplianceStatus', 
               ISNULL(TblLOGTMakerChecker.RoutineTaskOID, 0) AS MKOID, 
               ISNULL(TCSV.TaskComplianceStatusValue, '-') AS TaskComplianceStatusValue, 
               ISNULL(TL.TaskComplianceStatusValueOID, 0) AS TaskComplianceStatusValueOID, 
               @NoOfColorsInDashboardGraphs AS 'NoOfColorsOnReport', 
               @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasks AS 'TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTask', 
               @TerminologyToNonCompliedNonCompletedTasks AS 'TerminologyToNonCompliedNonCompletedTask', 
               @ShowPerformedOnDate AS 'ShowPerformedOnDate', 
               @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasksPerformedOnDtAfterDueDt AS 'TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasksPerformedOnDtAfterDueDt', 
               @TerminologyToCompliedTasks AS 'TerminologyToCompliedTasks', 
               (CASE
                    WHEN(
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM UnitTaskDocs
            WHERE UnitTaskOID = UT.UnitTaskOID
                  AND DueDateId = TL.OID
        ) > 0)
                    THEN 'Yes'
                    ELSE 'No'
                END) AS 'DocumentUploaded', 
               dbo.FormatDate
        (@ClientCode,
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 UPLOADED_DATE
            FROM UnitTaskDocs
            WHERE UnitTaskOID = UT.UnitTaskOID
                  AND DueDateId = TL.OID
            ORDER BY 1 DESC
        )
        ) AS 'DocUploadedDate', 
               (CASE
                    WHEN(
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM UnitTaskDoc_Reminder
            WHERE UnitTaskOID = UT.UnitTaskOID
                  AND RoutineTaskOID = TL.OID
        ) > 0)
                    THEN 'Yes'
                    ELSE 'No'
                END) AS 'DocumentUploadLater', 
               TL.FeesPaid, 
               TL.PenaltyPaid, 
               TL.SecondSupervisorComment, 
               TL.SecondSupervisorCommentDate, 
               TL.ThirdSupervisorComment, 
               TL.ThirdSupervisorCommentDate, 
               '' AS TaskType, 
               '-' AS Region, 
               '-' AS SubRegion
        FROM UnitTask UT
             INNER JOIN Task T ON T.Task_OID = UT.TaskOID
             INNER JOIN LegislationNames L ON L.LegislationOID = T.LegislationOID
             INNER JOIN LegislationCategories C ON C.LegislationCategoryOID = L.LegislationCategoryOID
             INNER JOIN [STATE] S ON S.STATE_OID = L.StateOID
             INNER JOIN Dept D ON D.DeptOID = UT.PerformerDeptOID
             INNER JOIN Units U ON U.UnitOID = UT.UnitOID
             INNER JOIN Entity E ON E.EntityOID = U.EntityOID
             INNER JOIN Priority P ON P.PriorityOID = T.PriorityOID
             INNER JOIN Frequency F ON F.FrequencyOID = T.FrequencyOID
             INNER JOIN RoutineTaskLog TL ON TL.UnitTaskOID = UT.UnitTaskOID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN RoutineMakerChecker TblLOGTMakerChecker ON TL.OID = TblLOGTMakerChecker.RoutineTaskOID
                                                                        AND TblLOGTMakerChecker.STATUS = 0
             LEFT OUTER JOIN TaskComplianceStatusValue TCSV ON TL.TaskComplianceStatusValueOID = TCSV.OID
             INNER JOIN LTGN_USER_DETAIL UDFH ON UDFH.USER_OID = D.DeptHeadOID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN LTGN_USER_DETAIL UDSup ON UDSup.USER_OID = TL.DeptSupervisorOID
             INNER JOIN LTGN_USER_DETAIL UDPer ON UDPer.USER_OID = TL.PerformerUserOID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN LTGN_USER_DETAIL UDComp ON UDComp.USER_OID = TL.CompletedByUserOID
        WHERE UT.[Status] = 'Active'
              AND UT.TaskStatus = 'Assigned'
              AND T.Devices = 'No'
              AND T.Title <> 'Applicability'
              AND L.LegislationCategoryOID NOT IN(117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125)
             AND T.CentralTaskOID NOT IN
        (
            SELECT CentralTaskOID
            FROM GroupTask
        )
             AND U.EntityOID IN(27, 25, 26, 24)
        AND u.UnitOID = UT.UnitOID
        AND ((TL.ReviewerDt >= '12/17/2019'
              AND TL.ReviewerDt <= '03/17/2020'
              AND TL.PerformerDt <= '03/17/2020')
             OR (TL.CompletedDt BETWEEN '12/17/2019' AND '03/17/2020')
             OR (TL.ApproverDt >= '12/17/2019'
                 AND TL.ApproverDt <= '03/17/2020'))
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TL.DailyTaskOID AS OID, 
               E.EntityOID, 
               U.UnitOID, 
               D.DeptOID, 
               E.EntityName, 
               U.UnitName, 
               D.DeptName, 
               (CASE
                    WHEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(U.ShortDesc)), '') = ''
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), UT.UnitTaskOID)
                    ELSE U.ShortDesc + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), UT.UnitTaskOID)
                END) AS 'UnitTaskWithDesc', 
               UT.[UnitTaskOID], 
               UT.[TaskOID], 
               T.LegislationOID, 
               T.CentralTaskOID, 
               L.LegislationCategoryOID, 
               C.LegislationCategory, 
               ISNULL(
        (
            SELECT C.CompanyCategory
            FROM CompanyCategory C
            WHERE C.CompanyCategoryOID = T.CompanyCategoryOID
        ), '-') CompanyCategory, 
               L.CentralState, 
               L.LegislationName, 
               T.Section_Rule_Regulation_Notification, 
               S.STATE_OID, 
               S.STATE_NAME, 
               T.[Title], 
               T.[PriorityOID], 
               P.Priority, 
               T.[FrequencyOID], 
               F.Frequency, 
               T.[Devices], 
               T.[Section_Rule_Regulation_Notification], 
               T.[Requirement_Apply], 
               T.[Task], 
               T.[Regulating_Authority], 
               T.[Consequences], 
               T.[Department], 
               TL.[Status] AS TaskStatus, 
               UT.PerformerUserOID, 
               D.DeptHeadOID, 
               ISNULL((UDFH.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UDFH.LAST_NAME), '-') AS 'DeptHead', 
               UT.DeptSupervisorOID, 
               ISNULL((UDSup.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UDSup.LAST_NAME), '-') AS 'Supervisor', 
               TL.PerformerUserOID AS 'PerformerUserOID_log', 
               ISNULL((UDPer.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UDPer.LAST_NAME), '-') AS 'Performer', 
               ISNULL((UDComp.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + UDComp.LAST_NAME), '-') AS 'TaskCompletedBy', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.ApproverDt) AS 'ApproverDt', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.ReviewerDt) AS 'ReviewerDt', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.SupervisorDt) AS 'SupervisorDt', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.PerformerDt) AS 'PerformerDt',
               CASE
                   WHEN @DeviationFunctionality = 'Yes'
                   THEN ISNULL(TL.Deviation, '-')
                   ELSE ''
               END AS 'Deviation', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.PerformedOnDt) AS 'PerformedOnDt', 
               dbo.FormatDate(@ClientCode, TL.CompletedDt) AS 'CompletedDt', 
               ISNULL(TL.Comments, '-') AS 'Comments', 
               ('-') AS 'ActivationComment', 
               ISNULL(TL.ReasonForNonComp, '-') AS 'ReasonForNonComp', 
               ISNULL(TL.ActionTaken, '-') AS 'ActionTaken', 
               dbo.GetCompletionDate(@ClientCode, TL.CompletedDt, @ShowPerformedOnDate, @NoOfColorsInDashboardGraphs, TL.PerformedOnDt) AS 'Completed On', 
               dbo.GetCompletionComment('', TL.Comments, TL.ReviewerComment, TL.CompletedDt, TL.ReviewerCommentDate, TL.PeriodFromDate, TL.PeriodToDate) AS 'CompletionComments', 
               '' AS UnitDeviceOID, 
               '' AS TaskDeviceOID, 
               '' AS 'lblUnitDeviceOIDDesc', 
               dbo.GetComplianceStatus(TL.[Status], CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), TL.ApproverDt, 112)), CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), TL.CompletedDt, 112)), @NoOfColorsInDashboardGraphs, @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasks, @TerminologyToNonCompliedNonCompletedTasks, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), TL.PerformedOnDt, 112)), @ShowPerformedOnDate, @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasksPerformedOnDtAfterDueDt, @TerminologyToCompliedTasks, @TerminologyToPosingRiskTasks) AS 'ComplianceStatus', 
               ISNULL(TblLOGTMakerChecker.DailyTaskOID, 0) AS MKOID, 
               ISNULL(TCSV.TaskComplianceStatusValue, '-') AS TaskComplianceStatusValue, 
               ISNULL(TL.TaskComplianceStatusValueOID, 0) AS TaskComplianceStatusValueOID, 
               @NoOfColorsInDashboardGraphs AS 'NoOfColorsOnReport', 
               @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasks AS 'TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTask', 
               @TerminologyToNonCompliedNonCompletedTasks AS 'TerminologyToNonCompliedNonCompletedTask', 
               @ShowPerformedOnDate AS 'ShowPerformedOnDate', 
               @TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasksPerformedOnDtAfterDueDt AS 'TerminologyToNonCompliedCompletedTasksPerformedOnDtAfterDueDt', 
               @TerminologyToCompliedTasks AS 'TerminologyToCompliedTasks', 
               (CASE
                    WHEN(
```

Comment: Kindly have a look into the post [Can we pass parameters to a view in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687279/can-we-pass-parameters-to-a-view-in-sql).

Comment: Please read the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as they tell you want you can and can't have in a view.

Comment: @SurajKumar went through that but can we direct make view by using my whole set of code

Comment: As per the docs - NO :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot declare variables in a view.

Comment: and if we remove the declaration part then we get error must declare variable  while making view

Comment: Yes, but it is still the answer to your question. You can't use undeclared, non-existing variables. You should try making it a stored procedure instead.

Comment: I have made stored procedure for given set of code too. But can we make view from stored procedure?

Comment: @DB_Bunny Try an inline table valued function - those you can use in a view.