# Create view with if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query where the result changes according to the parameter. I have created a stored procedure to show what I need. I want it in a view so that I can join with other tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SP_getTableByInputParameter]
    @inputParam INT
AS
BEGIN 
    IF (@inputParam = 1)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT
            cp.CompanyId, x.value AS Leavetypeid 
        FROM
            CompProperty CP 
        CROSS APPLY
            OPENJSON(cp.Properties, '$.Manageid') AS x
        WHERE
            CP.Properties IS NOT NULL 
            AND CP.CategoryId = 2 
            AND CP.Priority = 1 
            AND CP.Properties LIKE '%Manageid%'
    END
    ELSE IF (@inputParam = 2)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT 
            cp.CompanyId, x.value AS Leavetypeid 
        FROM
            CompProperty CP 
        CROSS APPLY
            OPENJSON(cp.Properties, '$.Unmanageid') AS x
        WHERE
            CP.Properties IS NOT NULL 
            AND CP.CategoryId = 2 
            AND CP.Priority = 1 
            AND CP.Properties LIKE '%UnManageid%'
    END
END
```

The view I need is something like

```
SELECT *
FROM company c
INNER JOIN SP_getTableByInputParameter(l) J ON c.companyid = J.companyid
```

I tried to create view as same as the procedure. But it didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Seems like you would rather have a Table-Valued Function

Comment: have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687279/can-we-pass-parameters-to-a-view-in-sql

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Are you actually using SQL2008, it doesn't have any JSON functions?

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on my comment AND offer a little twist ... Note the `CHOOSE()` function.

The dynamic JSON attribute will fail in 2016 but works in 2017+

**Example**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf_getTableByInputParameter]( @inputParam INT )

Returns Table 
As
Return (  

select cp.CompanyId
      ,x.value as Leavetypeid 
 from CompProperty CP 
 cross apply openjson(cp.Properties,choose(@inputParm,'$.Manageid','$.Unmanageid')) as x
 where  CP.Properties IS NOT NULL 
   and CP.CategoryId = 2 
   and CP.Priority = 1 
   and CP.Properties like choose(@inputParm,'%Manageid%','%UnManageid%')
)
```

**Usage**

```
Select *
 From [dbo].[tvf_getTableByInputParameter](1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an `IIF` or `CASE` within `OPENJSON`

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [SP_getTableByInputParameter]
    @inputParam INT
AS

SELECT
  cp.CompanyId,
  x.value AS Leavetypeid 
FROM
    CompProperty CP 
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(CP.Properties, IIF(@inputParam = 1, '$.Manageid', '$.Unmanageid')) AS x
WHERE CP.CategoryId = 2 
  AND CP.Priority = 1;
```

The `CROSS APPLY` will automatically remove any row which do not have the relevant JSON property, or are null.