# difference between output of sproc and functions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have been asked this question in the technical interview.

what is the difference between output of stored procedure and a function?

Can anybody please explain this?

Comment: Also, please search stackoverflow first before posting new questions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179758/function-vs-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

A user defined function can return a strongly defined scalar or a tabular value. Basically, a function can return any data type you can assign to a T-SQL variable or a rowset.

A stored procedure does not strongly define its return type. It can have zero, one or multiple result sets which can be of scalar or rowset values.

Comment: I don't know why I thought that. I removed that part of my answer. Also I should have ointed out that UDFs are "pure functions" with no side effects.

Comment: Also a stored procedure doesn't have to have any result set at all.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for clarifying. I updated y answer, but I already voted to close as duplicate.