# Create function to execute code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function, ssis

I would not normally use a function to execute code, but my boss is insisting on me using a function instead of an SP to execute SSIS packages. Don't really know why!

I need to create a function that will execute the following code and the user only need to provide the SSIS package name when calling the function.

```
declare @cmdtest varchar(200)
set @cmdtest = 'dtexec /f "C:\Users\Desktop\testpackage.dtsx"'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmdtest
```

This code above will execute my testpackage.dtsx, now my function must just ask for the SSIS package name and must be a varchar.

Since I am not clued up on functions can someone please show me what the best way of doing this is. I assume a Scalar Function needs to be used?

Comment: I don't think your boss understands what a function does in SQL Server. Have them read this, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179758/function-vs-stored-procedure-in-sql-server ... or find out why they insist on a function and share that information with us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ExecutePackage
(
    @PackageName VARCHAR(30)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cmdtest varchar(200);
    SET @cmdtest = 'dtexec /f "C:\Users\Desktop\'+ @PackageName + '.dtsx"';
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdtest;

    RETURN 1; --you could do some error checking and return either true or false - just a thought
END
```

Then you execute it as

```
SELECT dbo.ExecutePackage('testpackage');
```

Comment: I disagree with this approach. You're shoe-horning a function into a purpose not meant for a function, and you need to enable xp_cmdshell on the server to do so, and you will probably need to elevate rights for the caller as well.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I fully agree with you. Just answering the OP's question. There are always more ways to skin a cat.

Comment: xp_cmdshell is enabled on the server

Comment: @Etienne that doesn't make a function the right way to do this. I might have an ejector seat in my car but it's not the right way to drop my mother-in-law off at the mall.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree, but one have to do what the boss say you must do hey.

Comment: @Etienne like jump off a bridge? Sometimes you can question the boss and ask ***WHY***.

Comment: I think it is easier to explain to the boss why using a function is a bad idea in this case when you show the pitfalls of the implementation. Just saying functions aren't meant to do this is an overly abstract explanation to someone who doesn't fully understand the problem.

Comment: @Etienne: I think you should try to get your boss to explain to you exactly why he needs it in a function. Maybe he's just confusing functions and stored procedures?

Comment: @tobias86 I agree, going to tell him that I created what he asked but I will ask him why. I he very senior so I will have to ask him in a nice way and tell him that we should rather use a SP.

Comment: What would be the best practice here?