# Difference between stored procedure and function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function vs. Stored Procedure in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179758/function-vs-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)

I want to know what the differences between a stored procedure and a function in SQL Server are?

And where each one is used in ?

For example I have just written a stored procedure and I have finished it with

```
return @@Identity
```

So can we say is this a function because this will return a value?

These sort of problems has made me distracted.

Comment: search on google. I did..
About 698,000 results (0.32 seconds)

Comment: Here it is.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179758/function-vs-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Comment: Also: you should [use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` instead of `@@IDENTITY`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: "can we say is this a function because this will return a value?". If it begins `CREATE PROCEDURE` then it is a procedure. If it begins `CREATE FUNCTION` then it is a function.