# incorrect syntax : including results of stored procedure in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that does this...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetRegion @postcode nvarchar(10)
AS 
SELECT capt FROM REGION_DATA
where POSTCODE = @postcode
go
```

This means I can run

```
exec spGetCounty @postcode = 'rh12'
```

and it returns an area, such as "south east'

Is it possible to include the results of a stored procedure like this in a select statement. for example

```
SELECT 
  FIRST_NAME
, LAST_NAME
, POSTCODE
, << NEED TO INCLUDE RESULTS OF STORED PROCEDURE HERE PASSING IN POSTCODE
FROM PEOPLE
```

So something like

```
SELECT 
  FIRST_NAME
, LAST_NAME
, POSTCODE
, exec spGetCounty @postcode = 'rh12' << THIS BIT DOESN'T WORK !!
FROM PEOPLE
```

any ideas?

Comment: u can use table valued functions..

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506871/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-inside-a-select-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a stored procedure, consider using a scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION spGetRegion (
    @postcode nvarchar(10)
)
RETURNS varchar(255)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @capt varchar(255);

    SELECT @capt = capt
    FROM REGION_DATA
    where POSTCODE = @postcode;

    RETURN(@capt);
END;
```

Then you can call it as:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, POSTCODE,
       dbo.spGetRegion('rh12');
FROM PEOPLE;
```

Comment: you have mentioned `returns INT` and you have returned a varchar

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function

```
CREATE function spGetRegion 
(
    @postcode nvarchar(10)
)
RETURNS  varchar(100)
as
begin

    SELECT capt FROM REGION_DATA
    where POSTCODE = @postcode

end
```

and use it in your query like

```
SELECT 
FIRST_NAME
, LAST_NAME
, POSTCODE
, dbo.spGetCounty('rh12')
FROM PEOPLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't use stored procedure in select statement.

You have to use user defined function - **scaler function**.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetCounty] 
(
     @postcode nvarchar(10)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @capt VARCHAR(200)

    SELECT @capt = capt FROM REGION_DATA
    where POSTCODE = @postcode

    RETURN @capt
END
```

and then you can use it in select statement like this -

```
SELECT 
  FIRST_NAME
, LAST_NAME
, POSTCODE
, dbo.ufnGetCounty(postcode)
FROM PEOPLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use view or user defined function by referring below links

using view,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258253%28SQL.80%29.aspx

using user defined function
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175085%28SQL.80%29.aspx

A procedure can return multiple result sets, each with its own schema. It's not suitable for using in a SELECT statement.

or alternatively, try something like below

```
    SELECT  *  FROM    
    OPENQUERY(YOURSERVERNAME, 'EXEC MyProc @parameters')
    WHERE somefield = anyvalue
```