# MySql - Creating Stored Function and Calling It

Tags: mysql, stored-functions, database-management

I need help creating this particular stored function and call it by using the single select statement. Below are the questions with my answer. I think I got the first part right but I'm not sure. Any suggestions/advice? For the second question (part b), I'm calling the function incorrectly and can't get it to appear as specified in question/part b. Any advice? I would really appreciate the assistance.

Part A) Create a stored function called get_customer_balance which will return a customer’s balance from the membership table by passing in a membership number.

My Answer:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION get_customer_balance (membershipNo INT) 
RETURNS dec 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE CustBal dec;
SET CustBal = 0;
SELECT balance INTO CustBal  
FROM membership
WHERE membership_id = membershipNo;
RETURN CustBal;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[Part B question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPHLv.jpg)

[Membership Table. This is the original table of the problem (for reference guide)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x1p9.jpg)

Comment: answer is in this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506871/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-inside-a-select-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table membership
(   membership_id int primary key,
    balance decimal(10,2) not null
);

insert membership(membership_id,balance) values (1,1),(102,11),(103,109.25);

select membership_id,format(get_customer_balance(membership_id),2) as theBalance 
from membership 
where membership_id=102;

+---------------+------------+
| membership_id | theBalance |
+---------------+------------+
|           102 | 11.00      |
+---------------+------------+
```

Mysql Manual page on [Create Proc and Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)

Calling your user defined function (UDF) would be like calling any built-in function. Even if it involved joins on tables with aliases (which the above does not show).

A much better example would be one in which there are two tables. A `membership` table, and a `transaction` table that needs summed. But that wasn't your schema.

Would you like to see such a thing?

Comment: Thanks Drew! But I notice your first example is creating a table. I need to create a function. My table is already in the database.

Comment: I am using the function you created, and showed the data you did not have scripted. So I did not feel the need to re-show your function. I was focusing on the part of `how to call it` ... which was your question afterall, no ?

Comment: I don't get paid enough for this :P

Comment: when you are happy with Answers, give them a Green check mark signifying they are answered. Even if that means waiting a week or two

Comment: Will do. But there's an issue. The number 11 doesn't appear as 11.00 (with zeros) like displayed in the part b problem. Any idea why that is so? Is it because I might've done something wrong with my statement in part a?