# Use the result of Stored Procedure as column in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a sample Store Procedure:

```
dbo.spSampleProcedure
 @ID INT,
 @Country VARCHAR(50)
```

This SP will return a MONEY value(1 column only).

Now I want to implement it this way:

```
 SELECT 
    c.ID,
    Amount = EXEC spSampleProcedure @ID = c.ID, @Country = c.Country
 FROM Customer c
```

IS THIS POSSIBLE?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: What you are looking for is a `user defined function`

Comment: @PeterSmith Surprisingly, It doesnt work :(

Comment: @AsRa Do you mean converting the sp to function right?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506871/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-inside-a-select-query)

Comment: @FrancisLim  Yes.

Comment: @PeterSmith oh sorry! so it is not possible coz i wanna use a stored procedure because other dev is maintaining it and always updating. Just for re-usability. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider **NOT** naming your stored procedures using **sp_** as prefix. That is a system reserved prefix and it might cause performance issues. You can read more about it on [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) by Aaron Bertrand.

In order to do what you need you could first create a user defined function (as mentioned to you in the comments) that would do the following:

```
create function myfunc(@Id int, @Country varchar(50))
returns money
as
begin

declare @amount money 

select @amount = amount
from Customer 
where Id = @Id and Country = @Country

return @amount
end
```

Only then you can try what you wanted to do:

```
select  c.id,
        amount = dbo.myfunc (c.id, c.country)
from customer c
```

Comment: Thanks! now I know that it is impossible in stored procedure way because i wanna use the SP for maintenance and re-usability.