# Call stored MySQL function

Tags: java, mysql, stored-functions

I've created a stored function `verifierQteDemandee` in my database which has an integer parameter `numBonIn`, which returns a boolean value.

I want to execute this function in my java program, I googled about it and all I can find is to execute a stored procedure, however I assumed that executing a stored function is the same as executing a stored procedure, and this is the code I tried :

```
CallableStatement cStmt = con.prepareCall("{call verifierQteDemandee(?)}");
            cStmt.setInt("numBonIn", 42);
            boolean hadResults = cStmt.execute();
            if (hadResults) {
                ResultSet rs = cStmt.getResultSet();
            }
            Boolean outputValue = cStmt.getBoolean(outputValue);;
```

The `con` variable is ans instance of `Connection`.

As you can notice in my code I don"t know how I get the returned value from that stored function in this line : `int outputValue = cStmt.getInt("");`.

Please if someone knows how to get the returned value the procedure, I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
CallableStatement cStmt = con.prepareCall("{? = call verifierQteDemandee(?)}");
cStmt.registerOutParameter(1,java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN);
cStmt.setInt(2, 42);
cStmt.execute();
Boolean outputValue = cStmt.getBoolean(1);
```

Ça devrais fonctionner...!

Comment: Merci, ça fonctionne tres bien :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call verifierQteDemandee(?)}");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1,Type.Boolean);
cstmt.setInt("numBonIn", 42);
cstmt.execute();
bool outputValue = cstmt.getBoolean(1);
```

As a sidenote, I would not expect to obtain a resultset from an sql function! I would expect a scalar value as output from my sql function

Please refer to [Function vs. Stored Procedure in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179758/function-vs-stored-procedure-in-sql-server) for a complete comparison between function and stored procedure