# Database First Exception in Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

My Stored Procedure is::

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdvancedSearch] 
    @CompanyID bigint,
    @BookingReference nvarchar(15)

AS
Begin

declare @ExecuteSQL nvarchar(2000)
declare @WhereSQL nvarchar(2000)

if rtrim(isnull(@BookingReference,''))<>''
begin
set @WhereSQL = concat(@WhereSQL,' and
exists(select top 1 null from document (nolock) where document.dossierID=DossierHeader.DossierID and bookingreference like ''%' , @BookingReference , '%'' and Document.CompanyID=',@CompanyID,')')
end

set @ExecuteSQL=concat('
select top 10 dossier.DisplayID,dossierid,CustomerID,isnull(Customer.ShortName,Customer.[CustomerName]) as Customer,DossierHeader.InvoiceNumber,
from DossierHeader
join Customer
on DossierHeader.CustomerID=Customer.ID
where 
DossierHeader.CompanyID=',@CompanyID,@WhereSQL)

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @ExecuteSQL

end
```

And when I am using it in my code then on Debug I am getting some exception like::
[image: SP Exception]

How can I resolve this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `stored procedure` to `table value function` if you want the result of your nested select returned (stored procedures [return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx) execution return codes or output parameters).

The difference:

[Function vs. Stored Procedure in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179758/function-vs-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)

And the support of table valued functions by Entity Framework:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/01/21/table-valued-function-support.aspx