# Send string Parameter to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am Working on asp.net C# Project that connect to SQL Database (MySQL 2008).Here is my C# Class:

```
 public static DataTable GetUnitByName(string unit)
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        string sqlCommand = "GetUnitByName";
        DbCommand dbCommandWrapper = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommandWrapper, "@Unit", DbType.String, unit);
        DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommandWrapper);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        return dt;
    }
```

And Here is the Stored Procedure :

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUnitByName]
(
@Unit nvarchar
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @Err int
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
select * from Unit where Name=@Unit
   SET @Err = @@Error

    RETURN @Err
END
```

I call the Procedure Like this:
DataTable unit1 = Unit.GetUnitByName(per100gText[1]`enter code here`); , wich per10gText is a string list.
but it return empty datatable. the connection to sql server, in debuging i see that the procedure can't read the parameter.
Any Help Please.

Answer (score 0):

if you want proc to return param you need first to declare it as output param

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUnitByName]
(
@Unit nvarchar , @err int output
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
select * from Unit where Name=@Unit
   SET @Err = @@Error

    RETURN @Err
END
```

Comment: I don't use sql code often, can you explain more about function? and to return the value directly using sql and C#?

Comment: i dont know c# -:(   read this about proc and func:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179758/function-vs-stored-procedure-in-sql-server