# My query in sql server works very slow in a pc than gen9 proliant server

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-design, cpu-usage

I am trying to execute this query :

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPViewMTO] 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT      *,isnull(dbo.ReturnShortageByItemCodeLinePackage(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) As Shortage

           ,isnull(dbo.WarehouseByMaterialdesciptionId(MaterialDescriptionId),0) As Warehouse
           ,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalIMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as totalIMIV
,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as TotalMIV
,isnull(dbo.ReturnTotalMRCByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDesriptionId(LineId,TestPackageId,MaterialDescriptionId),0) as TotalMRC
 from dbo.ViewMTO

END
```

I run this query on this computer :

[image]

with  `2:13` execution time ,it is a little slow :
[image]

So our company decieded to buy a `proliant dl380 hp gen 9` with this config 
[image]

And i run the query again and i hope to my query execute more faster :
[image]

but the execution time is 4:10.Why?!!!
Another thing that i should add is the cpu usage in my local pc is :

[image]

And the server
[image]

Comment: This query is very simple, you don't have your problem here but on some or all these functions :

ReturnShortageByItemCodeLinePackage WarehouseByMaterialdesciptionId ReturnTotalIMIVByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDescriptionId ReturnTotalMRCByLineIdAndTestPackIdAndMaterialDesriptionId

Or the view : ViewMTO

You need to proportionate the code of those funcions and view if you want further opinions.

Comment: Those UDFs could be killing your query. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1179894/130352 which explains some of it.

Comment: @ChrisJ So how can i remove this function ?Can i bring the function code directly inside my storeprocedure?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - depending on the contents of the functions, yes. Or rewrite the functions to be table-valued rather than single-valued. But the only way to know is to profile.

Comment: You've got 5 UDFs that we can see, plus it looks like you're querying a view which could contain anything (including more UDFs, joins on non-indexed columns, non-sargable WHERE clauses, the list goes on). You're almost certainly in 'complete rewrite of the whole query' territory. But without seeing the contents of those UDFs and the view it's hard to give concrete suggestions.