# Better way to use SQL Server function?

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures, sql-function

Hey guys I want to use SQL Server function,

I never use function in SQL Server and I only know that function must return a value so I have two stored procedure `(1 for insert and 1 for select)`

My stored procedures look like this

For insert:

```
create proc INS_tblteststud  
@stdtid int=null,  
@name varchar(50) =null,  
@fullname varchar(50)=null,  
@address varchar(50)=null,  
@city varchar(50)=null,  
@country varchar(50)=null,  
@contno varchar(50)=null
as  
begin  
insert into tbl_student_test(name,fullname,address,city,country,contno)  
values  
(@name,@fullname,@address,@city,@country,@contno)  
end
```

And for select:

```
Create proc SEL_tblteststud  
as
begin
select * from tbl_student_test
end
```

Now I want to know, how can I convert these statements(Insert, Select) into functions? And which is better to use stored procedure or function?

Comment: You'd better read about functions because your "knowing" of functions is wrong. Functions cannot modify data and functions must not return a value, it's the worst case whan function returns a value (scalar function)

Comment: @sepupic thank you can you please recommend me something from the internet?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179758/function-vs-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing *procedure* and *function*...

- A *procedure* is meant for **doing** something
- A *function* is meant for **reading only**

It is not allowed to place data changing commands within a function.

What you are trying is just not possible...

### UPDATE Some insight about functions and procedures

There are three types of functions

- scalar functions: Return one scalar value and are **very bad performing**
- multi statement table valued functions (with `BEGIN ... END`): Return a resultset, but are **bad performing too**
- inline table valued functions: They are great, but restricted. Think of them like of a `VIEW` with pre-compiled parameters

A procedure has a return value too, which is of tpye `INT` and is not used to return the SP's result, but kind of execution status.

A SP might just do something and return no procedure result at all. If you want to return procedural results you must either use

- output parameters
- or you must call a `SELECT` within your SP. It is possible to grab the result of an internal `SELECT` from outside, but this is very cumbersome...