# SQL Server: use select/where/having statements in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I was reading this post [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900448/3453159) and I realize that we can't use a stored procedure in `SELECT / WHERE / HAVING` statements/clauses, but we can use them in an UDF, so why does this stored procedure work and return data?

I'm using select and having in this stored procedure:

```
create proc person_sp (@id int)
as
begin
    select id, [name], lastname 
    from person
    group by id, [name], lastname
    having sum(id) > 3
end
```

and then I called

```
exec person_sp 1
```

Comment: You can't call the stored procedure _from_ a SELECT query.  Eg `select * from person_sp 1` is illegal.  But you can call a UDF from a SELECT query eg `select * from personfunction(1) p`

Comment: You can't call a SP within a query, but you can issue any query within a SP (note the reversed terminology). Is that what's the question is about?

Comment: "I'm using select and having in this sp?"  Is this a question???  If it is, what is the actual question?

Comment: @Eric I mean if we can't use SELECT/WHERE/ HAVING statement in Sp so why in my code I can use having And I didn't get an error؟

Comment: Who says you can't use SELECT/WHERE/HAVING in sp?

Comment: @Eric look this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900448/3453159

Answer (score 1):

It's too long to put in comment, so I put it here.  In the link, it says " We can't use SP in SELECT/WHERE/ HAVING statement."
It means you can't call sp in your select/where/having statement. 
The statement below will error out.

```
select id, [name], lastname, exec person_sp 1
from person
where sp_another > 2
group by id, [name], lastname
having sum(id) > 3
```