# Why is SQL Server Table-Valued Function (TVL) so much slower via dynamic SQL generated by LINQ-to-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, user-defined-functions, database-performance, dynamic-sql

We have the following Sql Server Table-Valued Function (TVL) that retrieves all Users having a given phone number in 0.271 seconds:

```
select * from dbo.ClientsHavingPhoneNumberEver(null,'510','5273123',null,null,null)
GO
```

But, when the same TVL is executed with the same arguments via the dynamic SQL generated by a LINQ-to-SQL (L2SQL) data model it takes over 81 seconds:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].*
FROM [dbo].[ClientsHavingPhoneNumberEver](NULL, @p0, @p1, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS [t0]'
,N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'510',@p1=N'5273123'
GO
```

The above code snippet is abbreviated to spare you the trouble of reading a long list of select column names that do not change the performance.

Can anyone explain why the dynamic SQL execution is so much slower?

In case it matters, the TVL being called performs the union of three select statements:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ClientsHavingPhoneNumberEver
(   
    @countryCode nvarchar(10) = null,
    @areaCode nvarchar(50),
    @number nvarchar(100),
    @contactMethodTypeID int = null,
    @effectiveDate DateTime = null,
    @phoneRecordStateID int = null
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    select u.*
    from dbo.UserContactMethod ucm with (nolock)    -- select UserContactMethods by CountryCode, AreaCode and Number
    inner join dbo.Users u with (nolock) on ucm.UserID = u.UserID
                                    and (u.RecordStateID = dbo.RecordStateActive())
                                    and ((@phoneRecordStateID is null) or (ucm.RecordStateID = @phoneRecordStateID))
                                    and (((@contactMethodTypeID is null) and (ucm.ContactMethodTypeID in (dbo.ContactMethodCellPhone(), dbo.ContactMethodWorkPhone(), dbo.ContactMethodHomePhone())))
                                        or (ucm.ContactMethodTypeID = @contactMethodTypeID))
                                    and ((@countryCode is null) or (ucm.CountryCode is null) or (ucm.CountryCode = ucm.CountryCode))
                                    and (ucm.AreaCode is not null) -- include only phone numbers that have an area code
                                    and ((@areaCode is null) or (ucm.AreaCode = @areaCode))
                                    and (ucm.Number is not null) -- include only phone numbers that are not null
                                    and ((@number is null) or (ucm.Number like (@number + '%')))
                                    and ((@effectiveDate is null) or (ucm.EffectiveDate <= @effectiveDate))
                                    and ((@effectiveDate is null) or (ucm.ObsoleteDate is null) or (@effectiveDate < ucm.ObsoleteDate))
                                    and (dbo.IsStudent(ucm.UserID) = 0)
    UNION   -- select UserContactMethods by FullPhone
    select u.*
    from dbo.UserContactMethod ucm with (nolock) 
    inner join dbo.Users u with (nolock) on ucm.UserID = u.UserID
                                    and (u.RecordStateID = dbo.RecordStateActive())
                                    and ((@phoneRecordStateID is null) or (ucm.RecordStateID = @phoneRecordStateID))
                                    and (((@contactMethodTypeID is null) and (ucm.ContactMethodTypeID in (dbo.ContactMethodCellPhone(), dbo.ContactMethodWorkPhone(), dbo.ContactMethodHomePhone())))
                                        or (ucm.ContactMethodTypeID = @contactMethodTypeID))
                                    and (ucm.FullPhone like (isnull(@countryCode,'') + isnull(@areaCode,'') + @number + '%'))
                                    and ((@effectiveDate is null) or (ucm.EffectiveDate <= @effectiveDate))
                                    and ((@effectiveDate is null) or (ucm.ObsoleteDate is null) or (@effectiveDate < ucm.ObsoleteDate))
                                    and (dbo.IsStudent(ucm.UserID) = 0)
    UNION   -- select FormPersonContactMethods by CountryCode, AreaCode and Number
    select u.*
    from dbo.Form f with (nolock)
    inner join dbo.FormDetail fd with (nolock) on fd.FormID = f.FormID
                                        and f.RequiredTypeID = dbo.FormRequiredTypeID_Required() -- only required forms
                                        and f.RecordStateID = dbo.RecordStateActive()
                                        and fd.RecordStateID = dbo.RecordStateActive()
    inner join dbo.UserFormDetail ufd with (nolock) on fd.FormDetailID = ufd.FormDetailID 
                            and ufd.RecordStateID = dbo.RecordStateActive()
                            and (dbo.IsStudent(ufd.UserID) = 0)
    inner join dbo.FormPerson fp with (nolock) on ufd.UserFormDetailID = fp.UserFormDetailID
                            and fp.FormRoleTypeID in (dbo.FormPersonRole_PrimaryContact(), dbo.FormPersonRole_SecondaryContact(), dbo.FormPersonRole_AuthorizedPickupPerson())
                            and fp.RecordStateID = dbo.RecordStateActive()
                            and ((@effectiveDate is null) or (fp.EffectiveDate <= @effectiveDate))
                            and ((@effectiveDate is null) or (fp.ObsoleteDate is null) or (@effectiveDate < fp.ObsoleteDate))
    inner join dbo.FormPersonContactMethod fpcm with (nolock) on fp.FormPersonID = fpcm.FormPersonID
                            and ((@phoneRecordStateID is null) or (fpcm.RecordStateID = @phoneRecordStateID))
                            and (((@contactMethodTypeID is null) and (fpcm.ContactMethodTypeID in (dbo.ContactMethodCellPhone(), dbo.ContactMethodWorkPhone(), dbo.ContactMethodHomePhone())))
                                or (fpcm.ContactMethodTypeID = @contactMethodTypeID))
                            and ((@countryCode is null) or (fpcm.CountryCode is null) or (fpcm.CountryCode = fpcm.CountryCode))
                            and (fpcm.AreaCode is not null) -- include only phone numbers that have an area code
                            and ((@areaCode is null) or (fpcm.AreaCode = @areaCode))
                            and (fpcm.Number is not null) -- include only phone numbers that are not null
                            and ((@number is null) or (fpcm.Number like (@number + '%')))
                            and ((@effectiveDate is null) or (fpcm.EffectiveDate <= @effectiveDate))
                            and ((@effectiveDate is null) or (fpcm.ObsoleteDate is null) or (@effectiveDate < fpcm.ObsoleteDate))
    inner join dbo.Users u with (nolock) on ufd.UserID = u.UserID
                            and u.RecordStateID = dbo.RecordStateActive() 
                            and (dbo.IsStudent(u.UserID) = 0)
)
GO
```

Comment: Probably as it is using a cached plan compiled for different parameter values (parameter sniffing). That kind of "catch all" query could do with an `option(recompile)`.

Comment: Though another issue is that the parameter data types are nvarchar. If the columns aren't this might be the cause.

Comment: Good thinking, Martin. I checked the datatypes of all the phone number columns and they are all nvarchar and there are indices defined on each of them.   After I posted this question, my deadline forced me to rewrite the select statements inside the TVF so that the first two select statements of the UNION are consolidated into one select statement.  As a result, the performance is now comparable between the dynamic and static invocations.

Comment: I got another slight bump in performance from the following:

    ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.UserContactMethod
    REORGANIZE
    GO
    UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.UserContactMethod
    GO

Comment: I think this question is answered as soon as I figure out how to get my UDF to recompile itself.  I don't see a way to add the hint in C# above LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: According to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254814/sql-server-table-valued-functions-vs-stored-procedures] @gbn, "An inline table valued function (TVF) is like a macro: it's expanded into the outer query. It has no plan as such: the calling SQL has a plan."  That would explain why it's been difficult finding a way to add OPTION(RECOMPILE) to my TVFs.