# SQL function returning multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function, stored-procedures, sql-function

I am trying to create a simple function (or possible a stored procedure) that returns a list of values.

For example:

```
select title
from title
where tittle not in ('sample1','sample2',etc...)
```

so the results of this query will be:

```
title1
title2
title3
```

etc

I want to use this function over and over again in several other queries I have written, am just trying to avoid writing the long query which takes time and is tedious.

Not sure whether a stored procedure is best or function. and not sure which type of function is best (table?)

Comment: Not really clear on what you're asking... are you asking if you should use a table valued function or an SP, or are you asking about how to accomplish the other thing which doesn't have enough info provided to be of assistance? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178128/functions-vs-stored-procedures for a comparison of functions vs stored procedures

Comment: Yes i would like to know whats best a SP or table valued function. But i was reading that i cannot use SP in a select statement. I want to use this function in a select statement ... for example 
 

I am trying to create a simple function (or possible a stored procedure) that returns a list of values. For example:

select title
from title
where tittle not in (exec function)

again the function is going to return a list of values (one column)

Comment: It sounds like you already have your answer then :P