# Does SQL have a list type that can be used in a WHERE ... IN clause?

Tags: sql, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)
>   [SQL Server SP - Pass parameter for “IN” array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537087/sql-server-sp-pass-parameter-for-in-array-list)

I need to search for a haphazard set of integers on two different tables:

```
SELECT 
  col_1, col_2 
FROM 
  LIKES_NUMBERS 
WHERE 
  col_1 IN (1,2,3,5,7,1021,10041411)

SELECT 
  col_one, col_two 
FROM 
  LIKES_NAMES 
WHERE 
  col_one IN (1,2,3,5,7,1021,10041411)
```

Is there a SQL list type that can be passed to IN so that I don't repeat myself?  E.G.

```
DECLARE @stuff UNOBTAINIUM(1,2,3,5,7,1021,10041411)
-- ...
WHERE col_1 IN (@stuff)
-- ...
WHERE col_one IN (@stuff)
```

Creating a temporary table comes to mind, but that seems brutal.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537087/sql-server-sp-pass-parameter-for-in-array-list

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a [table variable](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-table-variables) for this. It's like a temp table, but locally scoped.

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked quite a number of times. [SQL Server SP - Pass parameter for “IN” array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537087/sql-server-sp-pass-parameter-for-in-array-list)

Also have a look at

- [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)
- [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005
  and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Comment: With search terms such as "SQL" "WHERE" "IN" "LIST", it's not easy to discover a previously-answered question.  Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1):

There's no list type.  Temporary table should be fine or you can use a table variable.

Answer (score 1):

When using MS-SQL, I tend to use XML documents for this purpose, which can be easily passed from non-SQL clients (unlike temp tables, I believe) and queried by MS-SQL's T-SQL syntax.

Comment: Show an example