# SQL comma separated values grouped in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 and inherited a database that did not use many to many. They instead used a comma-separated column. I have found how to link the comma-separated values to the name of the program. But I need a list of the programs and the offices they belong to, like this

`OFFICE` table:

```
ID  Name
--- ------
1   HQ
2   PA
3   CEO
```

`PRG` table:

```
ID  Name    Office Affected
--  ----    ---------------
A   PRG1    1,3
B   PRG2    2
C   PRG3    2,3
D   PRG4    1,2
```

Output that I need  :

```
Name    Programs
----    ---------
HQ      PRG1, PRG4
PA      PRG2, PRG3, PRG4
CEO     PRG1, PRG3
```

Comment: You **really** need to split the comma separated values out before you go any further.

Comment: Can you change your table definition?

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2009/06/23/in-with-a-comma-separated-list-sql-server/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553198/merge-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row/10553404#10553404

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333319/sql-in-variable-query/10333589#10333589

Comment: If you read my two answers, you can find **a** solution to your problem.  However, as @gvee mentioned, you really need to get rid of the CVS column else your performance will be poor.

Comment: No, the data and table were inherited.  The source code that uses the table (.net) was lost in a server crash.  I cannot change the database without affecting the program.  I am trying to get some information for other users.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage to do this.  However, because storing lists in strings is a bad idea, I don't want to compound that by putting them back in a comma-delimited list.  Instead, the following query produces the data in a more normalized form, with one row per office name and program:

```
select o.name, p.name as program_name
from prg p join
     office o
     on ','+p.OfficeAffected+',' like '%,'+cast(o.id as varchar(255)) + ',%';
```

Comment: Shoudnt p.id be o.id?