# How to use array of values in SQL Select - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)
>   [SQL Server SP - Pass parameter for “IN” array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537087/sql-server-sp-pass-parameter-for-in-array-list)

In my SP, I am taking string of data from Reference table to get the SQL select filtered.

here is scenario,

Regionids = 2,6,8
I get this value to a string @regions

In my SP i do calculations and atlast have a big SQL to return the data.
Based on Calculations, i get date and ids from which to get records. 
Also I want to restrict rows to above region specified in Reference.

So in my Where clause of the SELECT,
    AND RG.regionids IN ( @regions )

I get error, 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2,6,8' to data type int.

How can i accomplish above request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server SP - Pass parameter for "IN" array list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537087/sql-server-sp-pass-parameter-for-in-array-list) or [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use dynamic SQL:

```
EXECUTE('SELECT * 
         FROM   Region R 
         WHERE  R.RegionID IN (' + @regions + ')')
```

Comment: Just be aware that it is open to and SQL injection attack, especially if the @regions variable is user supplied.