# How to send multiple value with sql parameter for in()

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sqlparameter

I guess it is simple but I couldn't figure it out.
I want it for asp.net project.

Normally I use Int for sql parameter for one int value but I need it for in() statement.

```
alter procedure abc
  @id int

select * from tbl where id = @id
```

It works for one value,

```
alter procedure abc
  @id int -- how should I change it

select * from tbl where id in (@id)
```

that one which I want. And how can I send the values in asp.net c#. Normally I send int value, but I do not know either?

Comment: See here: [Pass array for in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537087/sql-server-sp-pass-parameter-for-in-array-list)

Comment: Possible may be duplicate, I heard new 'pass aray' (:
I'll check both of them