# Query to filter table where the condition is given as a comma separated string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need some help creating a query. Heres a sample table:

```
Segment   Name
1         Vincent
1         Jules
1         Lance
2         Vincent
3         Marsellus
4         Vincent
5         Marsellus
```

The problem is filtering this table. The column to filter on is the Segment column, and what to filter for is given as a string parameter, for example "1,2", meaning that I want Names that are in both Segment 1 and 2, returning the set:

```
Segment   Name
1         Vincent
2         Vincent
```

How can this be done? Help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Dynamic where-clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144550/sql-server-dynamic-where-clause)

Comment: if you are going to do a lot of this, it might be worth upgrading to 2008 where you can use table-valued input parameters in stored procs.

Comment: @HLGEM: I can't really see how table-valued input parameters is different than taking a comma seperated string, and converting it into a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you split the string you gets rows with values 1 and 2.
Then, you take the rows where the count of matches = the number of rows.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(8000)
SET @string = '1,2'

DECLARE @Mytable TABLE (Segment int, name varchar(8000))
INSERT @Mytable VALUES (1, 'Vincent')
INSERT @Mytable VALUES (1, 'Jules')
INSERT @Mytable VALUES (1, 'Lance')
INSERT @Mytable VALUES (2, 'Vincent')
INSERT @Mytable VALUES (3, 'Marsellus')
INSERT @Mytable VALUES (4, 'Vincent')
INSERT @Mytable VALUES (5, 'Marsellus')

;WITH Split AS
(
    SELECT SplitValue, COUNT(*) OVER() AS NumSplitValues
    FROM dbo.FN_ListToTable(',', @string)
)
SELECT
    [Name]
FROM
    @Mytable T
    JOIN
    SPLIT S ON T.Segment = S.SplitValue
GROUP BY
    [Name], S.NumSplitValues
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = S.NumSplitValues
```

If you need `Segment`, then join back thus

```
;WITH Split AS
(
    SELECT SplitValue, COUNT(*) OVER() AS NumSplitValues
    FROM dbo.FN_ListToTable(',', @string)
), Matches AS
(
    SELECT
        [Name]
    FROM
        @Mytable T
        JOIN
        SPLIT S ON T.Segment = S.SplitValue
    GROUP BY
        [Name], S.NumSplitValues
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) = S.NumSplitValues
)
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    Split S
    JOIN
    @Mytable T ON T.Segment = S.SplitValue
    JOIN
    Matches M ON T.[Name] = M.[Name]
```

The split functions relies on a numbers table and I grabbed it from google

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_ListToTable (
     @SplitOn  char(1)      --REQUIRED, the character to split the @List string on
    ,@List     varchar(8000)--REQUIRED, the list to split apart
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT
        SplitValue
        FROM (SELECT
                  LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(List2, number+1, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, List2, number+1)-number - 1))) AS SplitValue
                  FROM (
                           SELECT @SplitOn + @List + @SplitOn AS List2
                       ) AS dt
                      INNER JOIN Number n ON n.Number < LEN(dt.List2)
                  WHERE SUBSTRING(List2, number, 1) = @SplitOn
             ) dt2
        WHERE SplitValue IS NOT NULL AND SplitValue <> ''
);
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the great examples. Are there a more efficient way? My sample is a bit simpler than what I actually have, which counts lots of records, and joining back to get the Segment returned (your second sample), is a bit expensive and takes a long time.

Comment: @Tommy Jakobsen: You could load the split into a table var/temp table. My example splits twice which is bad of course, However, in one sense you already know the IDs from the call so do you need to get them back too? Unfortunately, it isn't an easy query to optimise

Comment: The split table is actually very small (mostly 2-5 records), so that is not the problem. Just wondering if there's a complete different solution.

Comment: @Tommy Jakobsen: not that I can think of. A temp table will perform better than a split though: try it. Even if it wasn't a split, I'd still use this solution. However, you already have 1,2 in the caller so I shouldn't need to return it, so my first solution which will be quicker can be used

Comment: I ended up using your solution :-) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one by creating a function that parses a string into a table. Specifically, I have an array of items in a web form and instead of loading these items individually from the form, I opted to accept all items as a single comma separated string.

```
/*********************************************************
** Parse A Comma Delimited String Into A Table
** Description: When A Web Page Sends An Array Of Data To
** The Server, The Array Is Comma Delimited.
** This Routine Returns All Of The Data From A Comma
** Delimited String Into A Table.
*********************************************************/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ParseByComma ( @String VARCHAR(600) )
RETURNS @TblSubString TABLE
(
 VarSubString VARCHAR(10)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intPos INT,
            @SubStr VARCHAR(10)
    -- Remove All Spaces
    SET @String = REPLACE(@String, ' ','')
    -- Find The First Comma
    SET @IntPos = CHARINDEX(',', @String)
    -- Loop Until There Is Nothing Left Of @String
    WHILE @IntPos > 0
    BEGIN
        -- Extract The String
        SET @SubStr = SUBSTRING(@String, 0, @IntPos)
        -- Insert The String Into The Table
        INSERT INTO @TblSubString (VarSubString) VALUES (@SubStr)
        -- Remove The String & Comma Separator From The Original
        SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String, LEN(@SubStr) + 2, LEN(@String) - LEN(@SubStr) + 1)
        -- Get The New Index To The String
        SET @IntPos = CHARINDEX(',', @String)
    END
    -- Return The Last One
    INSERT INTO @TblSubString (VarSubString) VALUES (@String)
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: That is only one part of the solution :)